# Adding Calendar Date Selector to Reputation Graph

Tags: feature-request, reputation-graph, dates

I think it would be nice to have a click-able date selector for the start and end dates of the reputation graph.  It would seem that this would be pretty trivial to implement, given all the other jQuery that is used on the site, in general.